# Which system calls will be used for command : cat < in (in is an existing regular file)?

Tags: filesystem, system, scripts

I am an undergraduate computer engineering student and this question is one of my system programming course's exam question.Actually the question is " will not be used" and the options are : open, create, read, write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them will be needed except `create` !

```
strace cat < yourPreciousFile
```

just in case it's not clear, the magic is done by `strace` which is a debug tool which is very useful in this scenarios.

Comment: I didn't know "strace" thank you so much it is so useful

Comment: btw, i couldn't see "crate" function, didn't it used ?

Comment: @myildirim my bad, no it's not used :(), it's the only one that is not being used.

Comment: that won't show the OS `open`ing the file. Might also look at `strace sh -c "cat < file"`